# Wowza Server Configuration On Amazon EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am struggling to configure the Wowza Media Server on Amazon Server.

**Success**: -  I have Successfully Installed Wowza Server on Amazon and Streaming is working with the Internal Private IP. Now, I have changed the Port from Default 1935 to Port 80. Now Binding with port 80 with Internal Private IP is working Fine i.e. 10.8.*.*:80 this works fine.

**Problem**: - Now, When I configure port 80 instead of my private 10.8.*.* to my Public IP 54.76.*.*
binding fails and i got error Bind Failed and Could not assign port. I have tried all the solution posted on stack overflow and also reinstalled the application several times.

**Solution Tried** : -

1) Restarting the Amazon and Wowza Server.
2) To verify firewall, I have installed IIS server and hosted dummy application it works with both private and public IP on port 80.
3) Installed Correct Java Version i.e. 1.8
4) Stopped the IIS server and Running Wowza Server.

Help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have done the configuration, for those who stuck with the same Issue, Just add the Inbound Rules for the Port you want to access. Also, Add the VHost details as, * in IP Address and 80 in Port, so all the IP:Port that are bind, will access the port.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you modify the security group settings and that all the appropriate ports are defined there.  I would also test playback with the aws url they provide to ensure it isn't an odd routing issue.  Lastly, you can review the [quick-start guide](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?191-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-for-Amazon-EC2-Quick-Start-Guide) for this process to ensure all basis are covered.

Lastly there are a ton of [pre-built AMI's](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?23-pre-built-amis-(amazon-machine-images)) just for this purpose as well.